# Change the destination View Controller of a tab in a Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I really like to know how can I change the link/destination ViewController for a tab bar item in swift.

My case:

```
if (beforeDayX)
{
    //TabBar[0] (Home) shows my1Scene with my1ViewController 
} else
{
    // TabBar[0] (Home) shows my2Scene with my2ViewController 
}
```

How should I do that? Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Initial answer was creating tabBar programmatically. But since the Josep (the questioner)  already have the tabBar created via Storyboard, I change the answer here to suit the need.

Assumptions:

(1) TabBar was created using UITabBarViewController. Class name: TabBarViewController

(2) Initially, the Tabbar consist of  WeekendVC,  WeekdayVC, OtherVC.

(3) Based on condition the Tabbar will either become: ( WeekendVC and OtherVC ) or  (WeekdayVC and OtherVC ) only.

Here is what the TabBarViewController will look like:

```
import UIKit

enum TypeOfDay {
    case weekday
    case weekend
}

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    var typeOfDay: TypeOfDay = .weekday

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initial order is: WeekendVC, WeekdayVC, OtherVC
        if let currentViewControllers = self.viewControllers {

            let weekendVC = currentViewControllers[0]
            let weekdayVC = currentViewControllers[1]
            let otherVC = currentViewControllers[2]

            switch typeOfDay {
            case .weekend:
                self.viewControllers = [weekendVC, otherVC]
            case .weekday:
                self.viewControllers = [weekdayVC, otherVC]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you satisfied with the answer, please accept and upvote it. If you have a further question please add a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much Shisui, that was my last option. The point is that I'm working with this project for 6 months and my tab bar is made with the storyboard, is there any way to do it just adding the minimum lines of code? Or I must do again my code? If the second is yes, what should I change in my code? And another thing, what if my first view controller is the one that I have to switch?

Comment: Josep, I've updated the answer to suit your requirement.  And you could arrange in any order as you want. Please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much man, I will edit your answer with my final code! Love you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. If you already have 5 tabs, means your currentVCs will have 5 VCs to play with. There is no 'new' instantiation. The instantiation of a VC only occurred when you pick a particular tab.  Or automatic pick for the first VC in new Array of  self.viewcontrollers when you  start the app.

Comment: First of all, sorry for my english explanation, grammar and vocabulary. To what I was referring to is that I had 5 view controller, one for each tab. What I wanted was to change one of them to another with an `if` condition, so if the 'if' was true, open the 'otherVC', else open the default one.

Comment: In this case, you have up to 5 VC to play with. Do whatever you want with them. Experiment with them.

Comment: Yes, I think so.  As long as you put them into the first tab, it will be automatically open when the App Started. For other tabs, you could still replace them but the user will need to manually tab it.